How can I display custom fields (created by ACF plugin) in WooCommerce Short Description?
I want to display custom fields in WooCommerce Short Description area, or after Short Description. The fields I created was using Advanced Custom Fields plugin, not default WooCommerce custom fields.
I found the following code, but added it to the functions.php file of my child theme, but unfortunately it doesn’t work.
function display_custom_field_woocommerce() {
global $post;
?>
<p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'finish', true); ?></p>
<?php
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_custom_field_woocommerce' );



‘finish’ is the custom field name in Advanced Custom Fields, while ‘woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form’ is the hook name. I suppose this code may only apply to custom fields created by built-in WooCommerce fields.

Using the plugin ACF, I have Field Groups, and make it only apply to a specific category of WooCommerce product.


There are 7-8 fields in that Field Group, is it possible to display all fields in that group?

Also I want to display both field label and field value.

I'm using Gutenberg instead of Elementor.
How can I edit that code?
I found that display custom fields created by ACF on WooCommerce single page is a lot more difficult than on post or pages.
ACF has short codes, but it seems not to work on WooCommerce single product page.
I also search online, and didn't find a way to display the field labels of ACF.
Thanks!

To get and display custom field values after the short description, we can use the woocommerce_single_product_summary hook with a priority to change the order of custom field content.
So, you can try the following code and update it according to your requirements.
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'gs_custom_field_value', 25 );
function gs_custom_field_value(){
    global $product;

    $value = get_field( 'finish', $product->get_id() );

    if( ! empty( $value ) ){
        echo '<p>'. $value . '</p>';
    }
}

Edited:
To get the ACF value and label use the get_field_object function, check the following code to get the custom field value and label.
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'gs_custom_field_value_label', 25 );
function gs_custom_field_value_label(){
    global $product;

    $field_object = get_field_object( 'product_data', $product->get_id() );

    if( ! empty( $field_object['value'] ) ){
        echo '<p><b>'.$field_object['label'].'</b>: '. $field_object['value'] . '</p>';
    }
}

Example:
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'gs_product_acf_value_label', 25 );
function gs_product_acf_value_label(){
    global $product;

    $material = get_field_object( 'material', $product->get_id() );
    $finish = get_field_object( 'finish', $product->get_id() );
    $width = get_field_object( 'width', $product->get_id() );
    $height = get_field_object( 'height', $product->get_id() );

    if( ! empty( $material['value'] ) ){
        echo '<p><b>'.$material['label'].'</b>: '. $material['value'] . '</p>';
    }
    if( ! empty( $finish['value'] ) ){
        echo '<p><b>'.$finish['label'].'</b>: '. $finish['value'] . '</p>';
    }
    if( ! empty( $width['value'] ) ){
        echo '<p><b>'.$width['label'].'</b>: '. $width['value'] . '</p>';
    }
    if( ! empty( $height['value'] ) ){
        echo '<p><b>'.$height['label'].'</b>: '. $height['value'] . '</p>';
    }
}


@Webwp check the code again, I have replaced the get_post_meta function with get_field of ACF, which I forgot to add in the code before.

Thanks for helping. I copied the code to functions.php file of my child theme, there is one problem. In the front end, the field value will be displayed twice. I want to display field label and field value. How can I edit the code? Thanks!

@Webwp check the additional code to get the ACF Label and Value.

There is still something wrong. I replaced that with the second code.  I have four custom fields, with label being "Material", "Finish",  "Width", "Height", with value being "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4". In the front end, I see only "f2" is displayed, no more information. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Pls send the screenshot of ACF fields

I'm not sure why I cannot attach image. These are the fields created by ACF. 1
Material - field name: material, value: f1
Finish - field name: field, value: f2
Width - field name: width, value: f3
Height - field name: height, value: f4

I have added the example code. Try to use it.

Did you add the "Material", "Finish", "Width", "Height" fields in groups? If yes, what is the group ID? https://prnt.sc/PnpHlAbn33An

@Webwp remove your website link from the comment, you cannot add it here. Simply explain what is the problem

This is in incognito mode, only f2 is displayed in the front end, f2 is the value of the field Finish https://prnt.sc/smLi4o54IL8T

This is no in incognito mode https://prnt.sc/JA7V4T7kdeoL   The following is displayed in separate rows:
Material: f1
Finish: f2
Width: f3
f2

I put Material", "Finish", "Width", "Height" fields in groups, there is no Group ID, only key: group_665bd3ae15649
https://prnt.sc/26ibOXLVf3Ry

Click here and send the screenshot https://prnt.sc/hflrXxVKYTxV

These are the field names: https://prnt.sc/tD5UULBI3cyZ

Using the same field settings and using Example code, the custom field data is showing for me https://prnt.sc/47X2DQENjgsY
Send the screenshot of code you are using.
